# Retrieve data from two tables in asp.net mvc using ADO.Net Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, join

Please read my question carefully and reply me.

I have two tables as table1 and table2.

In table1 I have columns as AddressID(Primary Key),Address1,Address2,City

In table2 I have columns as ContactID(Primary Key),AddressID(Foriegn Key),Last Name,First Name.

By using join operation I can retrieve data from both the tables.

I created a Model in my MVC Application. I can see both the tables in entity editor.

In the ViewData folder of my solution explorer I have created two class as ContactViewData.cs and SLXRepository.cs.

In the ContactViewData.cs, I have following code

```
public IEnumerable<CONTACT> contacts
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

In the SLXRepository.cs, I have following code

```
public  IEnumerable<CONTACT> GetContacts()
{
    var contact =
    (
        from c in context.CONTACT
            join a in context.ADDRESS on c.ADDRESSID equals a.ADDRESSID
            select new
            {
                a.ADDRESS1, 
                a.ADDRESS2,
                a.CITY,
                c.FIRSTNAME,
                c.LASTNAME
            }
    );

    return contact;
}
```

I am getting the error in return type

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SiennaSLX.Models.CONTACT>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Answer (score 1):

In Linq2Sql, your particular query will return an IQueryable object.

You can either change the return type of your method to IQueryable

```
public IQueryable<CONTACT> contacts
{
    get;
    set;
}

public  IQueryable<CONTACT> GetContacts()
{
    var contact =
    (
        from c in context.CONTACT
            join a in context.ADDRESS on c.ADDRESSID equals a.ADDRESSID
            select new
            {
                a.ADDRESS1, 
                a.ADDRESS2,
                a.CITY,
                c.FIRSTNAME,
                c.LASTNAME
            }
    );

    return contact;
}
```

or you can cast your return value with the .AsEnumerable() function:

```
public  IEnumerable<CONTACT> GetContacts()
{
    var contact =
    (
        from c in context.CONTACT
            join a in context.ADDRESS on c.ADDRESSID equals a.ADDRESSID
            select new
            {
                a.ADDRESS1, 
                a.ADDRESS2,
                a.CITY,
                c.FIRSTNAME,
                c.LASTNAME
            }
    );

    return contact.AsEnumerable();
}
```